# Access Basic Information About Apps On Device - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to create a basic app for iOS that helps users to cleanup the apps they have installed on their device. To do this, I would need to access basic information, such as which apps are installed and the last time they were used, use time in hours, etc. I know Apple is pretty strict on security and I haven't been able to find a way to do this in Apple's Developer documentation. Are there any APIs which allow for this kind of information access in Swift?

Comment: Nope. Can't be done.

Comment: *"I haven't been able to find a way to do this in Apple's Developer documentation"* - there is a very good reason for that, there is no such api.

Answer (score 0):

You can't accomplish this in IOS as there is a lot of security concerns as every app is supposed to access his sandbox only, even to know if app is installed is to have a url scheme of it and check if canOpen ...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it unless you jailbreak your iPhone. It is the same as rooting your Android phone.